# How to list all the archetype?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-archetype

Is there a maven command to list all the architype maven supports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you type

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

to generate a new project the first thing it does is presenting you a list of all available archetypes